# Multiple Projects from one Project with different ressource and config files

Tags: android, projects

I have one Project let us say pattern project. There are all sources and layouts for the different versions of the other projects. Without the drawables, because the other projects have different.

There are also 2 projects which use this pattern project es library. Which has there own drawable ressources and some own layout xml files.

This is working for me, I can compile it and on the device it is running.

But every time the workspace is building I get a lot of errors from the pattern project that there are no ressoruce files which are uses in the layout xml files.

```
res\layout\news_list.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/logosmall').
```

Is this normal? I'm using the wrong way to do it? How can I fix this?

I hope anyone of you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Library project is treated as a normal Android project by the build process, so if you want it to build without errors you have to include all referenced resources (or at least similarly named placeholders) in the Library project itself even if they are to be "overridden" by your application projects.